# I'm using the following snippet for Log rotation

Tags: shell, awk

Can some one explain how this works`ps -ef | grep mongod | awk '$0!~/grep/ && $2~/[0-9]/{print "kill -SIGUSR1 "$2}' | bash; find /tmp/logs/* -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: this is rather obvious : http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ps+-ef+%7C+grep+mongod+%7C+awk+%27%240%21~%2Fgrep%2F+%26%26+%242~%2F%5B0-9%5D%2F%7Bprint+%22kill+-SIGUSR1+%22%242%7D%27+%7C+bash%3B+find+%2Ftmp%2Flogs%2F*+-type+f+-mtime+%2B7+-exec+rm+%7B%7D+%5C%3B

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two things done here namely sending a signal to mongoDB to rotate logs and the second command removes logs older than 7 days.

The first command sequence does:

- `ps -ef` gets the full processlist in the form: UID PID PPID C STIME TTY  TIME CMD (or similar)
- `grep mongod` filters for the line of the mongoDB service
- `awk '$0!~/grep/ && $2~/[0-9]/{print "kill -SIGUSR1 "$2}'` filters to ignore the `grep` process and checks whether the second column (which should be the PID) is numeric. If both conditions are true it will print the message "kill -SIGUSR1" with the PID of mongoDB appended.
- `bash` the message 'printed' by `awk` is parsed through `bash`

After this command sequence the `find` command is invoked which in turn does:

- find files (`-type f`) in directory `/tmp/logs/*`, checks for modification time to be more or equal to 7 times 24 hours (`-mtime +7`) and invokes `rm` (`-exec rm {} \;`) to remove them.

See https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/rotate-log-files/ for details on rotating logs